# css3 text animation duration issue

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

Please see this fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/fn6eevew/1/

There are 6 text displayed in the above fiddle. I want displayed only 3 text. So i removed the 3 span tags. see the below fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/fn6eevew/2/

After the 3 span a long gap will be showed. What is the reason?? How can i fix this?? I can't understand.

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
0% { opacity: 0; -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; -webkit-transform: translateY(-200px) translateZ(300px) rotateY(-120deg); }
5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) translateZ(0px) rotateY(0deg); }
6% { text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1); color: #000; }
17% { opacity: 1; text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1); color: #000; }
20% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understand how this works.. Third span is last animated element, so there's no way anything else will come up afterwards. Like forever!

Comment: Do you mean there is a long gap because the animation has ended and if you wan it to restart you need to refresh the page?

Comment: Your link for version3 does not work and you should edit your post and add it in there.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fn6eevew/3/

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reduce the number of seconds that the animation runs for also. I have turned it down to 9 in the example below, You had it still at 18:

```
.rw-words span{position: absolute;font-size: 80px;left:0px;width:100%;text-align:center; top:25%;color: transparent;text-shadow: 0px 0px 80px rgba(255,255,255,1);opacity: 0;-webkit-animation: rotateWord 9s infinite;-ms-animation: rotateWord 9s infinite;animation: rotateWord 9s infinite; line-height:130px;}
```

I also removed the `nth-child` that are no longer needed in the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fn6eevew/4/)

How does this work for you?